# changes the type of values in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

In the dictionary below some of the `record_id` are in list and some are in integer. I'm trying to convert all the values of `record_id` to list of strings.

```
list_of_dict =      
    [{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': [4679], 'flag': 'N'}, 
     {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': 4678, 'flag': 'N'}]
```

I've tried below code:

```
for each in result:
    record_value = each['record_id']
    record_value = str(record_value)
    print(type(record_value))
    if type(record_value)1= list:
        record_value = record_value.split()
        each['record_id'] = record_value
```

expected output:

```
list_of_dict =      
    [{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': ['4679'], 'flag': 'N'},
     {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': ['4678'], 'flag': 'N'}]
```

please guide me with the solution

Comment: in the input if record_id is a list is there always one element? always an int?

Comment: @mozway record_id will always be integer but list may have more than one value.

Comment: I updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list/dictionary comprehension and a type check with `isinstance`:

```
[{k: list(map(str, v)) if isinstance(v, list) else v
  for k,v in d.items()}
  for d in list_of_dict]
```

output:

```
[{'f_text': 'sample',
  'symbol': '*',
  'f_id': 246,
  'record_id': ['4679'],
  'flag': 'N'},
 {'f_text': 'other text',
  'symbol': '!#',
  'f_id': 247,
  'record_id': 4678,
  'flag': 'N'}]
```

**edit** here is an alternative to ensure that the "record_id" are lists of strings

```
[{k: (list(map(str, v)) if isinstance(v, list) else [str(v)]) if k == 'record_id' else v
  for k,v in d.items()}
 for d in list_of_dict]
```

output:

```
[{'f_text': 'sample',
  'symbol': '*',
  'f_id': 246,
  'record_id': ['4679'],
  'flag': 'N'},
 {'f_text': 'other text',
  'symbol': '!#',
  'f_id': 247,
  'record_id': ['4678'],
  'flag': 'N'}]
```

Comment: but 'record_id':4678 is still not converted to list..i'm looking out like this[{'f_text': 'sample',
  'symbol': '*',
  'f_id': 246,
  'record_id': ['4679'],
  'flag': 'N'},
 {'f_text': 'other text',
  'symbol': '!#',
  'f_id': 247,
  'record_id': ['4678'],
  'flag': 'N'}]

Comment: @sruthi I had not seen this point, check my edit, also I asked a question as comment